# Keeping two processes alive in bash script (and respawning them when dead)

Tags: linux, bash

I used to have the following lines in my script in order to keep alive my process:

```
while [ -f $FILENAME ]
do
    echo "Running $BINNAME"
    ./$BINNAME >> $LOGNAME
    sleep 1
done
```

Which worked fine for me. But my problem comes when I try to achieve the same behavior but calling two processes. In other words, In need my script to launch both of them and, constantly check if they fall. If so, launching again the fallen process.

There is no possibility to use `pgrep` or `systemd`.

What would you suggest me?

I tried the following:

```
while [[ -f $FILENAME && -f $FILENAMEPROC ]]
do
    echo "Running $BINNAME + $BINNAMEPROC"
    ./$BINNAME >> $LOGNAME
    ./$BINNAMEPROC >> $LOGNAMEPROC
    sleep 1
done
```

But obviously, the script waits BINNAME to finish, then launches BINNAMEPROC. And this is not valid because I need both processes to be running simultaneosly.

Launching both on background with `&` and then using `ps | grep [name]` is also not valid because it could cause false possitives if someone adds a new process containing the string `name`.

Comment: `while ... done &` followed by `while ... done`

Comment: Why not fix what's causing them to fail?

Comment: `There is no possibility to use pgrep or systemd.` Great. What about supervisord? Why not run two bash scripts.

Comment: @KamilCuk using two bash scripts was the initial idea but I was trying to minimalize the FW package, just to simplify. Checked `supervisord` and it's also not available :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run your two `while` loops in parallel like this:

```
while : ; do
   echo 1 running
   sleep 3
done &

while : ; do
   echo 2 running
   sleep 3
done
```

The ampersand (&) after `done` puts the first loop into the background, thereby allowing the second loop to proceed in parallel.

Comment: Clean solution and works like a charm! Thank you. Didn't know this 'trick'. I've checked with `ps` that now I have two instances of my script. Guess they are the two tasks, right? Just to clarify

Comment: Glad it works for you. Technically they are two processes - the first in the background and the second in the foreground.

Comment: You could also put an ampersand (&) after the second `done` so it too goes into the background, then add a new last line with `wait` to wait for both loops to finish.